# How get html by dashboard like iOs UIWebView?

Tags: android, uiwebview, android-webview, obiee

I am new on OBIEE and I want to obtain the html code from a dashboard and see it on a Android WebView
I check this method:

```
http://server/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&PortalPath=/PATH
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e16364/apiwebintegrate.htm#i1053937

It returns a web page with flash element on Android, but on iOs (using UIWebView) the same request retrieve a HTML page with all I need without flash element (the graphs are replaced by static image).
How can i get the same data in Android WebView? I try to set the User Agent but the data not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I set the user agent of the WebView as:

```
web.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B141";
```

this code work on Monodroid.

All other user agents retrieve a web page containing some flash element.